# R regex extract number after/before string

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to construct a regex expression to identify string where the work "pack"/"pck"/"packs"/"Set" (case INsensitive) and if so (word exists), extract the number that precedes or follows this word. Examples:

```
"Fregon EcoClean Multipurpose Scrubber For Pots, Pans, Kitchen, and Bathroom, Green, 3-Pack" -> 3
Bathroom, Green, 3 Pack" -> 3
"Franklin Sports NHL Mini Hockey Goal Set of 2" ->2
"Make: Electronics Components Pack 2" -> 2
"Make: Electronics Components Pack of 2 -> 2
```

I tried using the following expression:

```
sub(".*pack(\\d+).*", "\\1", "inflow100 pack6 distance12")
```

However, it doesn't comply to all cases mentioned above.
Any ideas?

Comment: see my last example. Should return the number coming of "of"

Comment: Yes but that's a problem since you wrote earlier number **precedes or follows** the listed words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following regex matches all of the examples:

```
\b(?:(\d+)[-\s][Pp]ack|(?:[Pp]ack|[Ss]et)\s?(?:of\s)?(\d+))
```

See https://regex101.com/r/jZ4vE2/1

If you use it, you'll notice that the number is put in either \1 or \2. The only thing left to do, is to get rid of the preceding or following spaces.

```
> gsub(".*\\b(?:(\\d+)[-\\s][Pp]ack|(?:[Pp]ack|[Ss]et)\\s?(?:of\\s)?(\\d+)).*", "\\1 \\2", "inflow100 pack6 distance12", perl=TRUE)
[1] " 6"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just fetch the last number.

```
sub(".*\\b(\\d+).*", "\\1", str)
```

or

```
sub("(\\d+)\\D*$|.", "\\1", str)
```

Comment: This will fail if a description contains a number. Possibly it's good enough for Nirke, but we can't be sure, can we?

Comment: In R most of the answers are specific to user example only.. I will edit my answer, if op still have any issues.

Comment: The code will not fail if a description contains a number @mlambrichs. Try `'Xerox2100 Series 3 pack'`. I agree with Avinash also that we can easily overcode by imagining possibilities not applicable to the problem faced by the user.

Comment: Fair enough. But this would mean we could even ditch the \\b.

Comment: If you want to nitpick the code consider what happens with `'12 pack'` @mlambrichs. The above code does not produce the desired output. But then that's easily solved with `sub(".*(\\d+\\d+?).*", "\\1", x)` or the user's second option.

Comment: Pls. take a look at the user's question, again. How does "inflow100 pack6 distance12" fit?